# Can I make the tellraw command read from a JSON file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have some files of JSON chat data in a file with a code editor. I would like to have Minecraft read my file and output it as a chat component. I have wrote some pseudocode do show what I mean:

```
tellraw @a [ read contents of chat.json ]
```

Is there any command, mod, or server plugin that allows for this?

I am on Java 1.14 for Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no vanilla command or method of doing this in vanilla. I do not know of any server plugins or mods that implement this as a feature either; however, it seems like it could easily be implemented. The closest things I've found are just libraries for other plugins that create json and tell it directly to players instead of reading it from a file.